# Comparison of enol content

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

> How can we find the order of percentage of enol form
> of the compounds in the following equilibria?
>
> [image: org]

Percentage of enol form in *x* is highest as due to aromaticity. But how can we compare that for *y* and *z*. The compound *z* is non-aromatic but compound y has resonance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also think of **hydrogen bonding** here. See that in case of *y*, intramolecular hydrogen bonding is possible and hence greater percentage of enol content is of *y* than *z*. You may note that this is a general factor of esters (in this case a cyclic ester) in determining enol content percentage and that this factor may not always be the 'winning' one (as you can compare between *x* and *y*).

Comment: Do you mean *intermolecular* hydrogen bonding?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't the O serving to increase electron density in the C=O π* orbital, and thereby decreasing chances of enol formation?

Comment: The ring formed due to intramolecular H bonding wd be 4 membered thus destabilizing the enol.

Comment: 2nd compound seems to have more stable keto as well as more stable enol than the third compound due to conjugation. Either I am missing something or it wd be hard to compare without experimental data.